# INSERT INTO table with foreign key contraints

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, foreign-key-relationship, sql-insert

I have read a couple things on this and came up with the following code. I am using an Access database and am coding in C# through Visual Studio.

I am getting a syntax error in this. I have tried to create a query in Access to test this but its difficult to create this in that.

Can anyone help me figure out why this isnt working?

```
using(OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(global::InsulationProjectTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.InsulationDB))
{
    using(OleDbCommand command1 = conn1.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();

        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Jobsites (CustomerID, JobsiteName) VALUES ((SELECT Customers.CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE Customers.CustomerName = @cname1 AND Customers.BranchNumber = @bNumber1), @jName1)";
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@cName1", cboCustomerName.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@bNumber1", cboBranch.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@jName1", txtJobsiteName.Text));

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        command.Parameters.Clear();

    }
}
```

Tables setup

### Branches

PK BranchNumber
BranchName

### Customers

PK CustomerID
CustomerName
FK BranchNumber

### Jobsites

PK JobsiteID
JobsiteName
FK CustomerID

EDIT***

the below commmand produces no error, but also doesnt insert data into database

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Jobsites (CustomerID, JobsiteName) SELECT @jName1, c.CustomerID FROM Customers c WHERE c.CustomerName = @cname1 AND c.BranchNumber = @bNumber1";
```

Comment: Please clean up your code indentation.

Comment: Can you include your syntax error as well as the schema for Jobsites, Customers? Thanks

Comment: Parameter names are case sensitive.

Comment: `I am getting a syntax error...` try removing the `j` after `INSERT INTO Jobsites ` and before the `(j.Custome.....)`

Comment: Please include the exact text of the error message.

Comment: @SamAxe No, in OleDB, they're not.  In fact, they are all replaced with ? behind the scenes.  OleDB uses the index priority when assigning the parameter value.  So the user could just use `new OleDbParameter("?", ` in each of those parameter lines.

Comment: @SamAxe I apologize if i dont understand what you mean by "clean up your indentation". I am fairly new to stackoverflow and i tried to indent it correctly?

Comment: @LarsTech I admit it's been forever since I worked with OleDb.  That's for the correction.  -- That would mean that the query parser uses positional replacement for the parameters.. how would it resolve a query like:  `INSERT INTO theTable (ID, Key) VALUES (@theValue, @theValue)` ?

Comment: @phoog "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: @Josephff try pasting the SQL into a query's SQL view window and running it.  That should give you a better idea of where the error is.

Comment: @Josephff: I edited it for you.  you can see the difference.  In the future please make it easy for people to read your code.  It should look just like it does in VS.

Comment: @SamAxe Yes, or just `INSERT INTO theTable (ID, Key) VALUES (?, ?)`.  This applies to OleDb only.  The SqlClient namespace correctly uses the named parameters.  It resolves the parameters by finding the first non-field name as a parameter (? or @theValue) and applies the value you added in the code.  Index order of parameters is important with the OleDb namespace.

Comment: @LarsTech: good to know.  Thank you.

Comment: @SamAxe thank you for the indent corrections

Answer (score 3):

Access SQL does not accept an alias for the destination table.

For example, either of these statements trigger *"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."* ...

```sql
INSERT INTO Jobsites j (j.CustomerID, j.JobsiteName) VALUES (1, 'foo');
INSERT INTO Jobsites AS j (j.CustomerID, j.JobsiteName) VALUES (1, 'foo');
```

Without the alias, this one executes without error ...

```sql
INSERT INTO Jobsites (CustomerID, JobsiteName) VALUES (1, 'foo');
```

In order to get a query Access will accept, I think you may need to switch to an `INSERT ... SELECT` instead of `INSERT ... VALUES` ...

```sql
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Jobsites (CustomerID, JobsiteName) SELECT c.CustomerID, @jName1 FROM Customers AS C WHERE c.CustomerName = @cname1 AND c.BranchNumber = @bNumber1";
```

So basically what @ConradFrix suggested earlier but without the alias for the *Jobsites* table.

Comment: I didn't check does `Values (SELECT Col From Table, ?)` work ?

Comment: let me try this... However, i have used SQL earlier in this code using the Alias' with no error.

Comment: Aliases can be used for other types of Access SQL statements, but not for the destination table in an `INSERT`.  If you can find a way to do it, please show us a tested working example.

Comment: @ConradFrix i dont know. i've never used it before but i read that from a question i found on my search.

Comment: @HansUp, i thought you meant to remove them all, not just the INSERT table. What you said makes good sense and i will follow that rule going forward. Post edited with error after Alias removal.

Comment: how do I use a INSERT SELECT when i only want to select one of the (2) values. See above edit

Comment: You need 2 `VALUES` for the `INSERT`, so make sure the `SELECT` part returns 2 columns like this `SELECT c.CustomerID, @jName1`  In other words, include `@jName1` in the field list which follows the `SELECT` keyword.

Comment: revised edit above...no error but no data inserting into database either

Comment: What happens when you test the latest version of that `INSERT` statement in the Access query designer and supply the same parameter values?

Comment: i got it figured out, i had to rearrange all the parameters and stuff to match how do i address this as answered since there were so many helpful comments. Do i answer it myself and post what worked?

Comment: My understanding is that you should upvote all helpful answers.  Award the accept checkmark to the answer which you found most helpful.  If that's your own answer, I don't think that is a problem.  And your answer would likely be the clearest explanation of what finally worked.  :-)

Comment: No worries about the confusion. I wasn't sure that `Values (SELECT Col From Table, ?)` would be a problem. Some dbs support it although it's dangerous in my view. I undeleted my answer since it discusses how to deal with multiple rows returned otherwise I would have just let it be

Answer (score 2):

The answer suggested by KM in a comment is correct.  It is not possible (and there is no reason) to alias the target of an `INSERT INTO` query.  Instead, it should be

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Jobsites (CustomerID, JobsiteName) VALUES ((SELECT c.CustomerID FROM Customers c WHERE c.CustomerName = @cname1 AND c.BranchNumber = @bNumber1), @jName1)";
```

Comment: i got you. I thought he meant to remove all the Alias' not just the actual insert table. Makes sense....thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, Parameters name need the @ character, like in your query

```
"INSERT INTO Jobsites j (j.CustomerID, j.JobsiteName) VALUES ((SELECT c.CustomerID FROM Customers c WHERE c.CustomerName = @cname1 AND c.BranchNumber = @bNumber1), @jName1)"
```

so you need to change

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("cName1", cboCustomerName.Text));
                                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("bNumber1", cboBranch.Text));
                                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("jName1", txtJobsiteName.Text));
```

to

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@cName1", cboCustomerName.Text));
                                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@bNumber1", cboBranch.Text));
                                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@jName1", txtJobsiteName.Text));
```

Comment: OleDB doesn't actually use the parameter name, but they do have to be in the correct order.  You can just use "?" for all of those parameters.

Comment: I was checking the msdn documentation and they use the @ character in teh command.Parameters.Add `string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 LIKE ?";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Char, 3).Value = "a";
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();`
[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3)

Comment: i understand OleDb doesnt use the @ symbol and that it is in order, i just do it out of habit. I did mean to put the @ before the parameter identification and just forgot. Regardless, it didn't solve the error. I also use this format on other data queries with no problem. So i don't think using the @ symbol is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This part `VALUES ((SELECT c.CustomerID FROM Customers c WHERE c.Customer..`  is suspicious because using a SELECT for a single value to get the customerID might be tricky becuase of the potential of more than one CustomerID that meets your criteria.

One way to solve this is to rewrite the query to

```
command.CommandText =@"
    INSERT INTO Jobsites j 
      (j.CustomerID, j.JobsiteName) 
    SELECT c.CustomerID ,  @jName1 as Jobsitename 
    FROM Customers c 
    WHERE c.CustomerName = @cname1 AND c.BranchNumber = @bNumber1";
```

This uses a parameter as a constant for Jobsitename but it does mean that if more than one record was returned you'd get mulitple rows inserted.

You could prevent the possiblity of more than one record being returned by adding `TOP 1`

You could also query the database for the customer ID and check the row count before updating and throwing an exception if you did get more than one record. This would require two trips to the db but is possibly more correct (unless of course you have a unique index on customer name)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your help in solving this. I corrected several things based on the input that you provided.

The working code is as follow:

```
using(OleDbCommand command1 = conn1.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();

    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Jobsites (JobsiteName, CustomerID) SELECT @jName1, c.CustomerID FROM Customers c WHERE c.CustomerName = @cname1 AND c.BranchNumber = @bNumber1";
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@jName1", txtJobsiteName.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@cName1", cboCustomerName.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@bNumber1", cboBranch.Text));

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
    command.Parameters.Clear();


}
```

The main issue was i needed to use INSERT SELECT vs INSERT VALUES. Once i changed this, all i had to do was reposition the parameters and make sure they were in order and the code ran perfectly.

I also removed the alias designation on the INSERT INTO table as noted on here.

Thank you guys very much for your help!

-Joseph